# JodaTime PeriodFormat, Elapsed time with only 1 Field 

Tags: java, date, jodatime

How can we display the elapsed time with only 1 field.

For example

- Period = 1 Year 4 Months and 5 Days ==> Result = "1 Year ago"
- Period = 3 Months 5 Days ==> Result = "3 Months ago"
- Period = 4 Hours 5 Minutes ==> Result = "4 Hours ago"

So i just want the highest available field.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I was wondering how to get rid of those colors!

Answer (score 2):

There is no method in Joda-Time to do this, so you will have to test each field in turn manually.

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
val startDate = new DateTime(millis).withZone(dateTimeZone)
val endDate = new DateTime(dateTimeZone)

val period = new Period(startDate, endDate)

val localized = PeriodFormat.wordBased(localeLanguageCode).print(period)
val splitted = localized.split(",|and")
```

So, the splitted value will be an Array containing the period segments, from a bigger period to the lower one.

The Head of the array is the value you are looking for.

```
slitted.head + "Ago."
```

*You should change the REGEX pattern on the split method depending on your Locale or if you are using a custom formatter rather than the default one (PeriodFormatterBuilder)

Ex. Array("4 years", "2 months", "5 days", "18 hours", "15 minutes", "10 seconds", "50 milliseconds")

Answer (score 0):

The obvious algorithm would be to test if year > 0, in which case you use it, if not test if month > 0 etc.
There might be something more elegant but that would work in less than 15 lines of code...