# Period formatter to show two most significant units (e.g. "years, mon" for long period, "hours, mins" for short?)

Tags: jodatime

I have a Joda Time period formatter defined as below. I'd like it to show only the two most significant units.

So, for a long period it might produce "x years, y months". For a short period "x hours, y minutes".

What's the best way of achieving this with Joda?

```
val periodFormatter: PeriodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .printZeroNever().appendYears().appendSuffix(" year", " years")
    .appendSeparator(", ")
    .printZeroNever().appendMonths().appendSuffix(" month", " months")
    .appendSeparator(", ")
    .printZeroNever().appendDays().appendSuffix(" day", " days")
    .appendSeparator(", ")
    .printZeroNever().appendHours().appendSuffix(" hr", " hrs")
    .appendSeparator(", ")
    .printZeroRarelyLast().appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" min", " mins")
    .toFormatter();
```

Comment: Similar question: [JodaTime PeriodFormat, Elapsed time with only 1 Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140141/jodatime-periodformat-elapsed-time-with-only-1-field).

Answer (score 0):

The method `minimumPrintedDigits` applies to the "next and following appended fields".
Since you're using `printZeroNever`, I'dd suggest putting the `minimumPrintedDigits` method BEFORE the append methods.
Edit : it would work better using only `printZeroNever`.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my example. Any ideas on how I show only the two most significant units?

Comment: Since you will only see the units with non-null values, the two displayed units should automatically be the most significants. But it depends what kind of result you want : imagine we have 0 years 3 months 0 days 5 hours. Do you want to display "3 months 0 days" or rather "3 months 5 hours" ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think minimumPrintedDigits actually does what I need to do? If I have 3 mon 0 days 5 hours, I think ideally I'd like "3 mon 5 hours". If I have 3 mon 3 days 5 hours I'd like "3 mon 3 days" (that is, truncating the 5 hours as I only want two most significant units)

Comment: Let's say you have 2 years, 3 months, 0 days and 5 hours.
Using `printZeroNever` you should see 2Y - 3M - 5D. Since you're also using `minimumPrintedDigits` it will become 2Y - 3M (two fields as specified).

Comment: I don't think minimumPrintedDigits is related to my question (significant units).. minimumPrintedDigits only affects the presentation of individual numbers (padding them with zeros). I've decided to use PrettyTime instead of JodaTime to solve my problem.